# Ask for user input in a while loop

Tags: python-2.7

This example is supposed to get 5 words, then print them in reverse order.

This is what I tried:

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
    print "tell me word", n
    word(n) = raw_input()
    n = n - 1
print
r = 1
while r < 6:
    print word(r)
    r = r + 1
```

What is the correct way to assign like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a list.

```
words = []
```

Python won't let you assign using a previously unassigned index, so you need to call the `append` method:

```
n = 5
words = []
while n > 0:
    words.append(raw_input('Tell me a word: '))
    n -= 1
```

Notice I can use the first argument to `raw_input` to print a prompt, so there's no need to do that separately. You can also use the quicker `-=` to decrement and reassign `n`.

A `while` loop is sort of an unusual choice here, although it works. You'd be better off with a `for` loop using Python's built-in `range` function.

```
for n in range(5):
    words.append(raw_input('Tell me a word: '))
```

Once you're doing it like this you can even shorten it to a list comprehension and assign the list all at once:

```
words = [raw_input('Tell me a word: ') for n in range(5)]
```

Once you've got your list it's pretty simple to reverse it:

```
print list(reversed(words))
```

To print them one at a time (one per line) as you tried, you'd iterate over the list as such:

```
for word in reversed(words):
    print word
```

If you'd rather them be space-separated, Python 2 uses kind of a hack for this: print with a trailing comma.

```
for word in reversed(words):
    print word,  # note the comma!
```

I personally find the Python 3 version here a lot more readable. You can use it by doing `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your file:

```
for word in reversed(words):
    print(word, end=' ')
```

Note that if you do that (1.) it has to be right at the top of your file, and (2.) parentheses are required on all calls to `print` (because it's a function now).

Full script example (Python 2):

```
words = [raw_input('Tell me a word: ') for n in range(5)]
for word in reversed(words):
    print word,
```

PS - If you're just learning Python, why not use Python 3?

```
words = [input('Tell me a word: ') for n in range(5)]
for word in reversed(words):
    print(word, end=' ')
print()
```

Comment: thank you dude.. you might see how i've still got some Basic stuck in me..

you taught me a great deal.. square brackets for lists, defining the list first (words = [] ) 

and using append.. plus some short cuts and more.. you're a champion